# How to divide head to the three sections using primefaces panelGrid?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Assistance is needed in the division head to the three sections

```
    <!-- Header -->
        <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:150px;">
            <p:panelGrid columns="3" border="3">

            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:layout>
    <!--END of Header -->
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result is here]

Comment: I do not think I got the question well. Do you need a [nested layout](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/nested.xhtml)? `<p:panelGrid>` renders `<table>` which I do not think you will want for layout.

Comment: I want to be divided into three sections-Ras ,<p:panelGrid>
Image annex

Comment: @Tiny: `p:panelGrid` can render a table **or** a div based grid. The latter is accomplished by using the `layout="grid"` attribute. This works in 5.1 and up

Comment: What happened to the columnClasses? Seemed like a good idea

Comment: Of what? Try! Bang your head! Fail! Learn! And asking nicely gives you a greater chance of someone willing to